# How to enter a text in textbox (which makes AJAX calls) using JMeter?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jmeter

Help me with the steps to follow to enter a simple text into input box which contains AJAX calls as below using Jmeter.

> input name="investTrade:counterParty" id="investTrade:counterParty"
>   style="text-transform: uppercase;"
>   onchange="A4J.AJAX.Submit('_viewRoot','investTrade',event,{'control':this,'ignoreDupResponses':true,'status':'false','similarityGroupingId':'investTrade:j_id822','parameters':{'investTrade:j_id822':'investTrade:j_id822','ajaxSingle':'investTrade:counterParty'} ,'eventsQueue':'serialQueue','actionUrl':'/App/InvestTradeEdit.seam'}
>   )" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6

When I am trying to enter text such as "XYZ" in the textbox, the HTML content change as shown below:

> input name="investTrade:counterParty" id="investTrade:counterParty"
>   style="text-transform: uppercase;"
>   onchange="A4J.AJAX.Submit('_viewRoot','investTrade',event,{'control':this,'ignoreDupResponses':true,'status':'false','similarityGroupingId':'investTrade:j_id822','parameters':{'investTrade:j_id822':'investTrade:j_id822','ajaxSingle':'investTrade:counterParty'} ,'eventsQueue':'serialQueue','actionUrl':'/App/InvestTradeEdit.seam'}
>   )" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" value="XYZ" autocomplete="off">

The problem I am facing in JMeter, I have recorded user actions through HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder. All the user actions is properly recorded under Recording Controller. But when I am trying to run the recorded actions, I couldn't find the text entered in Response Data(View Result Tree). Dynamic values ($variable) passed under parameter section is not getting entered in textbox nor getting displayed.

What should I do after recording user actions? How to handle ajax calls in jmeter [please let me know clearly I have seen previous post related to this]? We are using seam framework with more AJAX functionality. Guide me friends! thanks :)

Comment: You should start by using fixed id's. j_id822 is an indication of a generated id. If it is different when playing back the script, it fails. Using fixed id's at least prevents this issue (not sure it will work then, but it is at least an improvement)